# Error while committing and pushing Java application from Eclipse to Openshift server (String in switch not supported)

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, openshift

### BUILD FAILURE

Hi,

I successfully set up everything to apply changes to my application located on Openshift server. Suddenly I decided to use some of my Java classes from other project and when I try to commit changes I get this error.

I am really hopeless with the error as I was researching for about a day and google just go blank on me with this and related questions. The problem is that I can't figure out what the "-source 7" stands for and if it related to the "-source 1.6" that is mentioned in the line above it in the error message.

Error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-   plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project organizer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/56c42c687628e1f0a2000073/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/organizer/DataOperations.java:[185,9] error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
```

This error is repeated for every instance of using String in switch statement.

EDIT: I am looking for a solution not only explanation. Trying to configure pom file atm.

I appreciate any help at all..

Thank you,

Ondrej

Comment: Java versions before Java 7 didn't support `String` in `switch` statements; using `-source 1.6` tells the compiler to compile the code as though it is Java 6 (or Java 1.6) code, which doesn't support `switch` for `String`, hence the build failure

Comment: I could have guessed that but I had no idea how to fix it. I am trying the solution below atm. Thanks for the clarifying comment though.

Comment: I just realized my question is not clearly stated as I search for solution and not only explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, String in Switch statements are only supported in Java 7+.

Looking at the error message you should update your POM to include the following i.e. explicitly compile against Java 7.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins?
    </pluginManagement>
<build>
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Pom.xml contained the source info and changing compiler source to 1.7 solved the issue. Build successful. Thanks!